# Adding a hint in editext after a set text

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I am building an app, and one of the things that I want to do is have a set text as well as a hint in the same edittext, right next to each other.  I want to show the user that the edittext can be used for more than one purpose.

like this:

**Text** more text if you want

Here is part of the xml file that I am using:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="location" />
```

Does anybody have any suggestion on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Be more specific! Explain properly what you wanna accomplish.

Comment: what exactly do you need here? why you're not using the built in hint property? everything that is not standard shouldn't be used since you want your users to feel "comfortable" with your app

Comment: Think it through what would happen when you set a static text after the user has put in their text. Would your _"hint text"_ stay there below the user input or move along? `HintText` by name gives a **hint** and disappears when there in an input.

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: As far as he explained, he needs text and hint both at a same time. Well it is not directly possible Hint and text at same time as far as i know. You can code it as per your logic manually.

Answer (score 0):

In your Java file create a member variable.

```
 private EditText mWhatYouWrite;
```

and then pass your widget's value using id.

```
 mWhatYouWrite = findViewById =(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
```

then simply create a field in string.xml of what you wanna write and pass in the value using setText();

```
 mWhatYouWrite.setText(R.string.key_of_your_string);
```

Hope It Helps!

Comment: Understand the question first.

Comment: Don't simply post answer. Look what he is asking first